# Azure devops interactive agent as admin

Tags: azure-devops, windows-10, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise VM running an Azure Devops Agent in Interactive mode. The agent runs using the only user the machine has, and it is an Administrator with UAC disabled. However, when executing tasks that require an elevated command prompt, as registering dlls, the command fails with the following error message:

```
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '5'.
```

And this message is when I'm trying to COPY files into Windows\SysWow64

```
##[error]Error: Failed cp: cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EPERM):C:\windows\SysWow64\test.txt
```

My testes also fail with the following error message:

```
Test method TestesRegressaoPGB.Autenticacao.AutenticarNoPGBL02 threw exception:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The requested operation requires elevation.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested operation requires elevation.
TestCleanup method TestesRegressaoPGB.Autenticacao.Cleanup threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

How do I run all commands while elevated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added permissions on each and every folder the pipeline agent needed to open. As I said to Vito, the agent was not running using a service account.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure DevOps, If you want to access local file in the azure devops pipeline via self-hosted agent, It accesses the file via `service account` instead of `Personal account`.

Workaround

We could open check the file permission and configure the service account permission. service account format User/Administrator/Administrators({Agent.ComputerName}\User/Administrator/Administrators)

Also, we could change the agent service account to your owner account.

Steps: Open service on the agent machine and search the agent service account, check the pic below, just change the account name and password to yours, then It will use this account to perform the operation.

[image]

Comment: Doing this does not work on my end, there's not even a Service with the same name as yours in the print. As I said, the agent is already running using an Administrator account, however, it always asks for elevation when trying to do an action through the pipeline. If I login in to the Virtual Machine and try to do the same action, it runs fine. It's just in the pipeline run context that it does not work.

Comment: Also, when I configured the Agent, I didn't use the Service Account, I used a personal account that is an Administrator.

Comment: "If I login in to the Virtual Machine and try to do the same action, it runs fine", this is you personal account, we create self-hosted agent via personal token and if we want to write local file via self-hosted agent, it do this via service account instead of personal account.

Comment: Interactive mode agents are not services, so they will never appear in Services. Also, they will not run under a Service account.