# Access Denied on Powershell Start-Process within AzureDevOps task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have an Azure DevOps task which needs to execute a Powershell script on a VM.  The inline script generates a credential which is used as a parameter for the Powershell process being started.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name $(MyVmName) -g My-RG --scripts `
        "`$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString `"$(PasswordSecret)`" -AsPlainText -Force" `
        "`$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'Vm1\localadmin',`$pw" `
        "Start-Process PowerShell -Cred `$cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File','C:\Users\localadmin\Documents\deploy.ps1'"
```

However, it appears that the Start-Process itself is getting Access Denied:

```
2021-04-21T22:15:29.6078202Z       "message": "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\1.1.8\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:3 char:1\n+ Start-Process PowerShell -Cred $cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', ...\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand"
```

The inline script below can be found on the vm and executed successfully using the same credentials that are used to generated the $cred.  But, I'm guessing that since the DevOps task is running under a different, less privileged account, it doesn't have access to the Start-Process cmdlet.

Is there a way around this?

(Note:  for several reasons beyond the scope of this post, I can't use the Powershell on Target Machines task, but I have in fact tried that.)

Comment: Hi Mike, You could check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65948178/13903626) to update the service account, then try it again and kindly share the result here.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @VitoLiu-MSFT.  However, it looks like that service account is on the azure pipelines agent itself, whereas my issue is on the target VM trying to run a script which has been pushed to it via the pipeline agent.  So there is no "Azure Pipelines Agent" service running on this VM.  The only azure related service I see running on the VM is AzureAttestService.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running as a hosted agent? Are you using a deployment pool?

What I've tried is setting the local deployment agent service credentials on the machine- the service has a name like `Azure Pipelines Agent`. You can configure a Log On As account in the services pane and restart the service to enable the agent to run as that account.

This isn't a full answer but I can revisit and update based on your response and maybe we can figure out our problems together.

Edit: ** After a couple hours of labor I've unblocked myself by using .cmd instead of powershell. I discovered though that because the agents are running as services the .exe is not being launched unless in *interactive* mode. The deployment will continually 'run' while the .exe is running, otherwise. Instead of doing this, I decided to just reboot the computer using cmd and having the start up task run what I need.

Maybe your answer could be similar: place the script with the agent into the startup task, then reboot the computer and allow it to run it on it's own.